# T-SQL to MS Access SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

I have a working query in SQL Server, but I fail to convert it to MS Access SQL.

This is the bare working query in SQL Server:

```
select tblKPIData.id
      ,tblKPIData.KPI_id
      ,tblKPI.KPI_Name
      ,tblKPIData.ImportTimestamp
      ,tblKPIData.Quantity
      ,tblKPIData.FinancialMonth
      ,tblKPIData.FinancialYear
      ,tblKPIData.Zone_id
      ,tblZone.ZoneName
      ,tblKPIData.DMA_id
      ,tblDMA.DMA_Name
      ,tblKPIData.TargetOrResult
from tblKPIData
inner join tblKPI
on tblKPI.Id = KPI_id
left outer join tblDMA
on tblDMA.Id = tblKPIData.DMA_id
left outer join tblZone
on tblZone.ID = tblKPIData.Zone_id
inner join tblDashboardKPI
on tblDashboardKPI.KPI_Id = tblKPIData.KPI_id
inner join
 (   select a.kpi_id
           ,a.financialMonth
           ,a.financialYear
           ,isnull(a.zone_id,0) as zone_id
           ,isnull(a.dma_id,0) as dma_id
           ,a.targetorresult
           ,max(a.importtimestamp) as importtimestamp
     from tblKPIData a
     group by kpi_id
     ,financialMonth
     ,financialYear
     ,zone_id
     ,dma_id
     ,targetorresult) as max_kpi
on (tblKPIData.KPI_id = max_kpi.KPI_id
and tblKPIData.ImportTimestamp = max_kpi.importtimestamp
and tblKPIData.FinancialMonth = max_kpi.FinancialMonth
and tblKPIData.FinancialYear = max_kpi.FinancialYear
and isnull(tblKPIData.Zone_id,0) = isnull(max_kpi.zone_id,0)
and isnull(tblKPIData.DMA_id,0) = isnull(max_kpi.dma_id,0)
and tblKPIData.TargetOrResult = max_kpi.TargetOrResult)
where tblKPIData.FinancialMonth = 'Oct'
and tblKPIData.FinancialYear = 2017
and tblKPIData.KPI_id in (select kpi_id from tblDashboardKPI where tblDashboardKPI.KPI_Id = tblKPIData.KPI_id)
and (tblKPIData.Zone_id = 5 or tblKPIData.DMA_id in (select id from tblDMA where Zoneid = 5))
AND ((tblDashboardKPI.Status) = 1)
and ((tblDashboardKPI.Dashboard_Id) = 6)
```

I know I have to add brackets, but not exactly sure where. This is what I came up with, but I get an error (Join Expression not supported) and it highlites a piece of code on the first join (tblKPI.Id = KPI_id):

```
select tblKPIData.id
      ,tblKPIData.KPI_id
      ,tblKPI.KPI_Name
      ,tblKPIData.ImportTimestamp
      ,tblKPIData.Quantity
      ,tblKPIData.FinancialMonth
      ,tblKPIData.FinancialYear
      ,tblKPIData.Zone_id
      ,tblZone.ZoneName
      ,tblKPIData.DMA_id
      ,tblDMA.DMA_Name
      ,tblKPIData.TargetOrResult
from (((((tblKPIData
inner join tblKPI
on tblKPI.Id = KPI_id)
left outer join tblDMA
on tblDMA.Id = tblKPIData.DMA_id)
left outer join tblZone
on tblZone.ID = tblKPIData.Zone_id)
inner join tblDashboardKPI
on tblDashboardKPI.KPI_Id = tblKPIData.KPI_id)
inner join
 (   select a.kpi_id
           ,a.financialMonth
           ,a.financialYear
           ,isnull(a.zone_id,0) as zone_id
           ,isnull(a.dma_id,0) as dma_id
           ,a.targetorresult
           ,max(a.importtimestamp) as importtimestamp
     from tblKPIData a
     group by kpi_id
     ,financialMonth
     ,financialYear
     ,zone_id
     ,dma_id
     ,targetorresult) as max_kpi
on (tblKPIData.KPI_id = max_kpi.KPI_id)
and tblKPIData.ImportTimestamp = max_kpi.importtimestamp
and tblKPIData.FinancialMonth = max_kpi.FinancialMonth
and tblKPIData.FinancialYear = max_kpi.FinancialYear
and isnull(tblKPIData.Zone_id,0) = isnull(max_kpi.zone_id,0)
and isnull(tblKPIData.DMA_id,0) = isnull(max_kpi.dma_id,0)
and tblKPIData.TargetOrResult = max_kpi.TargetOrResult)
where tblKPIData.FinancialMonth = 'Oct'
and tblKPIData.FinancialYear = 2017
and tblKPIData.KPI_id in (select kpi_id from tblDashboardKPI where tblDashboardKPI.KPI_Id = tblKPIData.KPI_id)
and (tblKPIData.Zone_id = 5 or tblKPIData.DMA_id in (select id from tblDMA where Zoneid = 5))
AND ((tblDashboardKPI.Status) = 1)
and ((tblDashboardKPI.Dashboard_Id) = 6)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Access doesn't understand the OUTER JOIN syntax.  Usually you can get away with a LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: You need `from tblKPIData inner join tblKPI on tblKPI.Id = tblKPIData.KPI_id`  Access will accept left joins!

Comment: on (tblKPIData.KPI_id = max_kpi.KPI_id) <-- you also have to delete this bracket

Comment: If the data hasn't actually moved into an Access database file, I would suggest to run a **Pass-Through query** in Access, which is executed in SQL Server. This query with multiple LEFT JOINs and subquery looks like it might perform horribly in Access.

Comment: Removing the OUTER part works in SQL, but in Access I still get the same error on the same piece of code.

Comment: Thanx, Dymeng, Jonathan and jetblack, I made the changes you  suggested and got a little futher (to the next error ;-)

Comment: If all of your data is stored in SQL Server you could use a [pass through query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/303968/how-to-create-an-sql-pass-through-query-in-access) instead.  These allow you to execute T-SQL from MS Access.

Comment: `IsNull()` is something different in Access SQL than in T-SQL. Use `Nz()` instead.

Comment: Even better than a pass through query would be to create this as a procedure on the sql server side and then execute it from Access.

Comment: @Dymeng How does a LEFT JOIN 'usually' substitute for an OUTER JOIN?

Comment: @nicomp: It doesn't, but the query uses only `left outer join`, which translates into `left join`.